# Angular error text not displayed when testing invalid form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-test

In my Angular app, I have a simple component that contains a form with a text input field.

This input fields accepts only string shorter than 255 characters. When the user inserts a text longer than 255 characters, an error is displayed:

[image]

This is the test case I've written:

```
it('should display error when the inserted description text is too long', () => {
  const inputElement: HTMLInputElement = hostElement.querySelector('.input-element');

  inputElement.value = getRandomString(256);
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const errorElement: HTMLElement = hostElement.querySelector('.error-element');

  expect(errorElement).toBeTruthy();
  expect(errorElement.innerText).toContain('Please enter no more than 255 characters.');
});
```

However despite I'm using `fixture.detectChanges()` after dispatching the `input` event, and despite the form control status is INVALID and has the error (I checked by debugging the code), the error message is not shown while the test run, so the expectations fail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the error message is actually not being displayed until the user moves out from the field (e.g. clicking somewhere else or pressing the TAB key).

So in order to fix this, we need the `inputElement` to dispatch a **blur** event:

`inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));`

The test now looks like this:

```
it('should display error when the inserted description text is too long', () => {
  const inputElement: HTMLInputElement = hostElement.querySelector('.input-element');

  inputElement.value = getRandomString(256);
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur')); // this line has been added
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const errorElement: HTMLElement = hostElement.querySelector('.error-element');

  expect(errorElement).toBeTruthy();
  expect(errorElement.innerText).toContain('Please enter no more than 255 characters.');
});
```